Exclusion Keywords for filter subscription email notifications?
I have a filter subscription notification set up at https://stackexchange.com/filters to get daily emails for new story-identification posts, but I would like to exclude any posts on certain tags/topics (like manga/manhua/manwha and fanfic) from the email digest that I receive.

Is there any way to do this? The ignored tags panel doesn't affect this.

I assume you've ignored those tags?

What part of the site are you asking about specifically? There are several features which do some sort of notification.

You would have thought so, but no, I hadn't done the obvious thing. Thanks.

Okay, so that didn't appear to work. I added "manga" to my ignored tags, but in my "New story-identification questions" filter subscription daily email, manga results continue to show up. The ignore tags don't appear to be excluded from the filter subscription, and there doesn't seem to be any way to exclude content from the new questions subscription.

Oh, you mean the email notifications at https://stackexchange.com/filters/ - I recommend [edit]ing your question to clarify that this is what you meant.

Since this is about the Stack Exchange Filtered Questions, currently there is no way to exclude tags from there.
Related feature request:

How to exclude (ignore) specific tags in filters (for subscription)?
Add "I'd like to exclude..." option to Stack Exchange filters

